# How do I allow an DIV needing text input to do multiple functions?

Tags: jquery

In my HTML I have this div;

```
<div id="genComments" class="editGComms"> </div>
```

I need to do several things with this div;

1. I need to prompt for some information like this.

   var WRU = prompt("Your Call?").toUpperCase();
2. If WRU has a value then I need empty the div of any previous data that might have been there. Like this.

   empty(genComments);
3. But then I need to allow #genComments to be edited with text. And that text must be prefixed with the data returned from the prompt. Which might look like this "WA0TJT". But I can't figure out how to allow the field to be edited at this point. The cursor is no longer in the div, and if I put it back into it the process start over. I don't want to make the additional text a prompt, I want to directly input it into the div.

My jQuery code looks like this;

```
$(".editGComms").click(function() {
    var WRU = prompt("Your Call?").toUpperCase();    
    $('#genComments').empty();
});
```

The combination of the two pieces of text will then be shown in the div and by other functions (already working) added to MySQL.

Can someone please advise me how to accomplish the 3 steps above?

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: It's unclear what you do with that `var WRU`, Text sould be prefixed with `WA0TJT` ? But editable? A DIV? you mean `contenteditable` or `textarea` or `input`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".editGComms").on("click", function() {

  if (this.value.trim()) return; // We have some value! do nothing on click!
  
  // 1. Remove existing value
  // $(this).empty(); <<< this makes no sense since it's already empty
  
  // 2. Ask user for value
  const WRU = prompt("Your Call?");  
  
  // 3. Make sure there's a valid user-input
  if (!WRU.trim()) return alert("Invalid value");
  
  // 4. Insert user value
  this.value = WRU;  
});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

.editGComms {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
PS: Insert: wa0tjt<br>
<input class="editGComms">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I goofed up your code. Your example works perfect but unfortunately doesn't translate to what I need. After taking the WA0TJT input, the div (you use input) needs to be edited, something will be typed into it, which will have the WA0TJT pre-pended to it. The function that edits it is a jquery editable function. But it never runs after something is typed in the div.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issues by first using jQuery to empty the div like this;

```
$('.editGComms').on("click", function(){
    $('.editGComms').empty(); 
});
```

Then to allow editing, saving the data to MySQL, and making the div ready for new input;

```
function RefreshGenComm() {
    var str = $("#idofnet").html();
        $.get('getGenComments.php', {q: str}, function(data) {
            $(".editGComms").html(unescape(data));
        }); // end response
}
```